# std::vector resize downward

Tags: c++, vector, resize, std, stdvector

The C++ standard seems to make no statement regarding side-effects on capacity by either 
`resize(n)`, with `n < size()`, or `clear()`.

It does make a statement about amortized cost of `push_back` and `pop_back` - O(1)

I can envision an implementation that does the usual sort of capacity changes 
ala CLRS Algorithms (e.g. double when enlarging, halve when decreasing `size to < capacity()/4`).
(Cormen Lieserson Rivest Stein)

Does anyone have a reference for any implementation restrictions?

Answer (score 63):

Calling `resize()` with a smaller size has no effect on the capacity of a `vector`. It will not free memory.

The standard idiom for freeing memory from a `vector` is to `swap()` it with an empty temporary `vector`: `std::vector<T>().swap(vec);`. If you want to resize downwards you'd need to copy from your original vector into a new local temporary vector and then swap the resulting vector with your original.

**Updated:** C++11 added a member function [`shrink_to_fit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) for this purpose, it's a non-binding request to reduce `capacity()` to `size()`.

Comment: The way I read it he's asking about the impact on memory usage - he specifically asks what the effect on capacity is of resize. The standard doesn't specify the result in that case but the only reason to ask I can think of is a desire to free unused memory. The swap with temporary trick is the idiomatic way of achieving that.

Comment: The standard does specify the result by not specifying a decrease of capacity() for these operations. Therefore it can't decrease.

Comment: There are some environments where it is forbidden to allocate or free memory after an initial 'construction' phase. Vectors are usable in this environment as long as one can be sure they don't attempt to allocate or free memory during operations. So this question is relevant in this situation (which brought me here).

Comment: with g++ and libstdc++ 10: std::vector::shrink_to_fit does a fresh allocation. `myvector.data()` yields a different address every time I call shrink_to_fit()

Answer (score 32):

Actually, the standard does specify what should happen:

This is from `vector`, but the theme is the same for all the containers (`list`, `deque`, etc...)

> 23.2.4.2 vector capacity [lib.vector.capacity]

`void resize(size_type sz, T c = T());`

> 6) Effects:

```
if (sz > size())
    insert(end(), sz-size(), c);
else if (sz < size())
    erase(begin()+sz, end());
else
    ; //do nothing
```

That is to say: If the size specified to `resize` is less than the number of elements, those elements will be erased from the container. Regarding `capacity()`, this depends on what `erase()` does to it.

I cannot locate it in the standard, but I'm pretty sure `clear()` is defined to be:

```
void clear()
{
    erase(begin(), end());
}
```

Therefore, the effects `clear()` has on `capacity()` is also tied to the effects `erase()` has on it. According to the standard:

> 23.2.4.3 vector modifiers [lib.vector.modifiers]

```
iterator erase(iterator position);
iterator erase(iterator first, iterator last);
```

> 4) Complexity: The destructor of T is called the number of times equal to the number of the elements erased....

This means that the elements will be destructed, but the memory will remain intact. `erase()` has no effect on capacity, therefore `resize()` and `clear()` also have no effect.

Comment: `resize` downward is now documented as equivalent to a series of `pop_back()` calls and not `erase`.  Does that remove the guarantee that capacity won't change?  (See http://stackoverflow.com/q/19941601/103167)

Answer (score 7):

The capacity will never decrease. I'm not sure if the standard states this explicitly, but it is implied: iterators and references to vector's elements must not be invalidated by `resize(n)` if `n < capacity()`.

Answer (score 0):

As i checked for gcc (mingw) the only way to free vector capacity is what mattnewport says.
Swaping it with other teporary vector.
This code makes it for gcc.

```
template<typename C> void shrinkContainer(C &container) {
    if (container.size() != container.capacity()) {
        C tmp = container;
        swap(container, tmp);
    }
    //container.size() == container.capacity()
}
```