# Does resize() to a smaller size discard the reservation made by earlier reserve()?

Tags: c++, vector, containers, std

So if I reserve(100) first, add some elements, and then resize(0) (or any other number smaller than the current size), will the vector reallocate memory to a take less space than 100 elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vector<T>::resize(0)` should not cause a reallocation or deletion of allocated memory, and for this reason in most cases is preferable to `vector<T>::clear()`.

For more detail see answers to this question: [std::vector resize downward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155693/stdvector-resize-downward)

Comment: `clear` doesn't cause a reallocation either, so I don't see why it would be preferable...

Comment: I've seen at least one implementation where `clear` freed the memory.

Comment: @MarkB: It shouldn't have. :P

Comment: @GManNickG While that's true (reference?) sometimes in programming you have to be pragmatic based on the tools you have access to/are forced to use.

Comment: @MarkB: For sure, but when something deviates from the standard it's usually not worth worrying about because, when it *does* happen, you don't need to be told; it's a bug! Reference is actually in the linked question from this answer. The C++11 standard clarifies that only `shrink_to_fit()` should be expected to modify capacity, and even that's non-binding.

Comment: @GManNickG: I'm curious: where does C++11 state that `clear` shouldn't modify the capacity?

Comment: @NicolBolas: §23.3.6.3/6 says (cutting), "...It is guaranteed that no reallocation takes place during insertions that happen after
a call to `reserve()` until the time when an insertion would make the size of the vector greater than the value of `capacity()`." Meaning you must be able to call `clear()` and then still be able to insert until the reserved limit is reached. (Also, `clear()` is defined in the 'generic' table 100 at §23.2.3 to only destroy elements, which means capacity is unchanged.)

Comment: Great comment, GMan! Maybe modify the answer to account for the standard clear() behavior? Also, about "preferable", it is very subjective :P In my case I wanted the exact behaviour of resize() - to not reallocate (and thus save time).

Answer (score 2):

Doing a `vector::resize(0)` or to a smaller count rather than current count should not deallocate any memory. However, it may destroy these elements.

For a reference on `std::vector::resize`, take a look at [std::vector::resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)