# usage of the returned iterator from std::unique

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T>
int eliminate_duplicate(vector<T> &A) {
  sort(A.begin(), A.end());  // makes identical elements become neighbors
  auto it = unique(A.begin(), A.end());  // removes neighboring duplicates
  A.resize(it - A.cbegin());  // truncates the unnecessary trailing part
  return it - A.cbegin(); // Question> Is this line valid?
}
```

Is the last line valid?

Here is my concern: after the calling of `resize`, the iterator `it` will point to a invalidate location, so can we still use it as `it - A.cbegin()` in the return line?

Comment: Why not simply store the result in a variable *before* you resize?

Comment: What you should do it `A.erase(it, A.end())`.

Comment: How about `A.erase( unique( A.begin(), A.end() ), A.end() )`?

Comment: If the `resize` causes a reallocation, then any existing iterators are invalidated...

Comment: It's not valid. Invalidated iterators are invalidated.

Comment: I don't know if it's an guarantee, but I would be really surprised if resize() would do any sort of re allocation when shrinking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155693/stdvector-resize-downward -- why do you think resizing with a smaller size could invalidate?  Ah, because `it` now points to past-the-end without being created via calling `end()`.

Comment: This is not my code and please simply focus on whether or not it is correct.

Comment: Another way to phrase this question: if you erase the last element of a `std::vector`, does the iterator that referred to it now a past-the-end iterator?  I think the answer is "no, but many implementations will quite often give that result" -- and that is strong enough that you could probably add it to the next version of the standard and only the debugging version of `std::vector` iterators would have to be changed!  (as, under-the-hood, the easy way to implement a fast `vector` iterator is to be a gussied up pointer)

Answer (score 3):

From section *23.3.6.3 vector capacity* of the C++11 standard (draft n3337), clause 9 (the bolded text is my emphasis as it is the case in the posted code that `sz <= size()` is true):

```
void resize(size_type sz);
```

> Effects: **If sz <= size(), equivalent to erase(begin() + sz, end());**. If size() < sz, appends sz - size() value-initialized elements to the sequence.

and from section *23.3.6.5 vector modifiers*, clause 3:

```
iterator erase(const_iterator position);
iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
```

> Effects: Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase.

`begin() + sz` is equal to `it`, therefore `it` is invalidated.

To correct, just return `A.size()` (if the caller really requires it as that information is available from `A` anyway). Suggest using `A.erase(it, A.end());` (as commented by [juanchopanza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661519/juanchopanza)) as the intent of the code is clearer.

Comment: On the other hand, it's guaranteed to be past-the-end (i.e. end()), and you are allowed to do end()-begin().

Comment: @DanielKO, not sure I follow as in `end() - begin()` there is no reference to a previously stored `iterator`?

Comment: As vector is guaranteed to be contiguous, and data is not moved when shrinking, "it" has to point to where a push_back() will emplace the next item (if there's capacity for it), so it's essentially the same as end(). But as the standard is over-conservative (it erase() should invalidate references at and after, but invalidate iterators only strictly after, allowing erase(end()) to be a no-op) I think an implementation could go out of its way to make sure that line breaks (like storing a few flags and such). You are correct.